# AWS MediaConvert on media that has no audio

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, media

I am currenly creating a MediaConvert job from my Lambda function in AWS and using it to convert my media and also create thumbnails.  However it is failing when trying to convert media that has no audio on it.

> Invalid audio track specified for audio_selector [1]. Audio track [1]
>   not found in input container.

Is there a way to process media if it has no audio?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the issue as well and solved it by removing the track number in the AudioSelectors section. It seems to work for videos with and without audio tracks.

```
    "AudioSelectors": {
      "Audio Selector 1": {
        "Offset": 0,
        "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
        "SelectorType": "TRACK",
        "ProgramSelection": 1
      }
    }
```

Comment: Not working for me, could I see your entire configuration?

Comment: @AlejandroCuervo - Try this instead:

`"AudioSelectors": {
    "Audio Selector 1": {
        "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT"
    }
}`

Comment: Having the same problem and removing the `Tracks` property allows videos without audio tracks to be converted.