# MediaConvert transcoding failed with No audio frames decoded on [selector-(Audio Selector 1)-track-1-drc]

Tags: aws-media-convert

Audio file(m4a) uploaded does not get transcoded instead raised error

```
No audio frames decoded on [selector-(Audio Selector 1)-track-1-drc]
```

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527221/aws-mediaconvert-on-media-that-has-no-audio) but it did not worked. I believe its happening because of malfunction in the device that audio has been recorded, but I'm not sure about it

Does anybody faced this? and resolved this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

The selector is (most likely) not finding the content at the specified location ; or is unable to decode the data found there.  An inability to decode data may be due to an unsupported data type, or possibly data corruption.

We suggest inspecting the source file with a media utility to confirm whether the file actually has audio data in a supported format on track 1;  Or, trying another source file which you are certain has data on track 1.

One way to automate and adjust this input mapping process is to probe the file with a Lambda function (typically triggered by s3 file events) and use that information to customize a MediaConvert job template to create job settings tuned for that source file.

This blog post has more information:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/processing-user-generated-content-using-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg/